# How to derive this result?

Tags: algorithms

Problem is to find the total number of zeroes in the decimal representation for the series with input $N$

> $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... \text{upto} \, N$

due to time limit constraints run time complexity was needed to be minimized. 
I attempted it and couldn't clear all the test cases. The solution talks about the use
of this equation

> number_of_zeros$(10*N+C)$ = $10*($number_of_zeros$(N)−1) + N − (9−C)*Z + 1$

where

> number_of_zeroes$(N)$ = number of zeroes for the input $N$
>   $C$ is any number between $0$ and $9$ inclusive
>   $Z$ is the number of zeroes in decimal representation of $N$

I'm trying to derive this result but no success so far.
I also think It was not very intuitive to think in this direction or is there any simple fact I missed here.

thanks

Comment: link to the original solution: [here](http://blog.codility.com/2011/12/mu-2011-certificate-solution.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to calculate N and C, which is easily done with division and modulo operators. I'm using `%` as modulo here, which is common in many languages. Name the input to `number_of_zeroes` as `K`. Then:

```
N = K / 10 (integer division!)
C = K % 10
```

Now you can use `N` and `C` to implement `number_of_zeroes` as a recursive function.

You still must calculate `Z`, though. The naive solution is to do that in a loop as well, but we can be smarter. The number of zeroes in 6043 is exactly the same as the number of zeroes in 60435, right? We can thus calculate `Z` *once* and then send it along as a parameter in the recursive calls, decrementing it with 1 each time `C == 0`.

Comment: problem asks to calculate the total 0's . and reason why I brought this equation is because the solution using modulo and division will time out.

Comment: You are correct, the naive solution gives you quadratic runtime complexity. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, but the original time complexity is O((log N)2) . please have a look at this solution article. [here](http://blog.codility.com/2011/12/mu-2011-certificate-solution.html)

Comment: Depends on what your N is in complexity analysis. Is it the number of digits so that 1000 is twice as large as 10, or is it the integer value so that 1000 is 100 times larger? It's quadratic with the former interpretation (which I used) and NlogN with the latter (which the article use).

Comment: problem gets a positive integer N as the input and the solution is based on reduction.  the equations simply means that if we know the solution for N, we can get the solution for the number 10*N + C hence we can build the solution iteratively upto N .

Comment: actual problem is the deriving the used equation which didn't occur to me at all and I am wondering why ? as the problem was supposed to be solve in under 30 minutes . :-)